# Ember.Select two way binding for edit form

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my ember application I have defined a select element like this in my template:

```
{{view Ember.Select
    content=greetings
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.code"
    value=selectedGreeting
    selection=selectedGreeting
    prompt="Please choose"}}
```

The controller for this page (shared form and controller for create and edit form) looks like this:

```
greetings: [
    {code: "Mr.", id: 1},
    {code: "Mrs.", id: 2}
],
selectedGreeting: null,
actions: {
    save: function(){
        var person = this.get('model');
        if (person == null || person.id == undefined)
        {
            // create mode
            var greeting = this.selectedGreeting.id;
            // ....
            var newPerson = this.get('store').createRecord('person',{
                greeting: greeting,
                // ..
            });
            newPerson.save();
            this.transitionToRoute('index');
        }
        else
        {
            // edit mode
            person.set('greeting', this.selectedGreeting.id);
            person.save();
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfect when creating a new person, but when opening an existing one the select box shows the promt instead of the saved value (do I really have to do this with jQuery?).

Besides I suppose there must be an easier way to update the existing model with the selected values in the else branch, as the other properties get modified automagically.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, the documentation for Ember unfortunately does not help a lot in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ember.Select` view has quite a few quirks. In fact, if I remember correctly, I saw an issue on Github to just have the whole thing rewritten. For now, I'm assuming that the `prompt` attribute takes precedence over the `selection` attribute. To get around that, I would just use a conditional in the template.

```
{{#if model}}
    {{view Ember.Select ... value=selectedGreeting}}
{{else}}
    {{view Ember.Select ... prompt='Please Choose'}}
{{/if}}
```

Also, your second question, if I understand you correctly, you should be able to just use `selection=model.greeting` to bind the selection value to the model property. And if you're using the template above, you can make it so it only applies to the former and not the latter.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve it, the #if model condition works but the selection does not get set on the dropdown. I've tried selectedGreeting and model.greeting, no effect.

Comment: I just wrote a small wrapper component for Ember.Select, and I used `value` instead of `selection`. Are you using only `value` and not also `selection`?

Comment: I got it fixed today using:
`{{view Ember.Select
        content=greetings
        optionValuePath="content.id"
        optionLabelPath="content.code"
        value=model.greeting
    }}'

This works in both ways - loading the data from model and saving the data to the model. Please edit your answer accordingly and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: By the way {{#if model}} works only for the first load of the create form, after it has been loaded model is not empty any more.

Comment: I solved this last problem by using {{#if model.id}}. I set model to Ember.Object.create({}) in the create route and model.id is only filled for existing persons, so this is reliable for edit mode in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed using:

```
{{view Ember.Select
    content=greetings
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.code"
    value=model.greeting
    prompt="Please select"
}}
```

This works in both ways - loading the data from model and saving the data to the model. The prompt does not interfere with the value from what I experienced.